# Unable to use Context inside Firebase valueEventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-context

I am trying to retrieve a list of items from `Firebase` and after all the data is retrieved, I want to inflate the data in `listView` using an adaptor. Here is the code I am using:

```
vehicleReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        ServiceHistoryDataModel serviceHistoryData = data.getValue(ServiceHistoryDataModel.class);
                        serviceHistoryDataList.add(serviceHistoryData);
                    }

                    ServiceHistoryListAdapter adapter = new ServiceHistoryListAdapter (this,serviceHistoryDataList,getLayoutInflater());
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }else
                    Toast.makeText(ServiceHistoryActivity.this, "No service history available !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

(please refer the screenshot)

**I am getting an error :-**

> "ServiceHistoryListAdpter() in ServiceHistoryListAdapter cannot be
>   applied:..."

**For the line:**

```
ServiceHistoryListAdapter adapter = new ServiceHistoryListAdapter (this,serviceHistoryDataList,getLayoutInflater());
```

Could you please let me know how can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: It is not working even with activity name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ServiceHistoryListAdapter adapter = new ServiceHistoryListAdapter(YourActivityName.this,serviceHistoryDataList,getLayoutInflater());
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to access the instance of enclosing class from the anonymous class. The syntax for which is `EnclosingClassName.this`.
So change the line to:

```
ServiceHistoryListAdapter adapter = new ServiceHistoryListAdapter(YourActivityName.this,serviceHistoryDataList,getLayoutInflater());
```

i.e. add `YourActivityName.` before `this`.

Comment: Redundant answer !

Comment: I was the first to answer this question and the second person answered it after me some seconds later. Please remove the down vote if you've done it.

Comment: @RishabhSaxena I'm aware that the answers should not be redundant.

Comment: @RishabhSaxena Done!

Comment: Up vote mine answer too, If you are satisfied ! I have upvoted yours

Answer (score 1):

Just pass parameter like "YourActivityName.this" your problem will be resolved.
Check out code below for the same.

```
ServiceHistoryListAdapter adapter = new ServiceHistoryListAdapter(YourActivityName.this,serviceHistoryDataList,getLayoutInflater());
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace

```
ServiceHistoryListAdapter adapter = new ServiceHistoryListAdapter(this,serviceHistoryDataList,getLayoutInflater());
```

with

```
ServiceHistoryListAdapter adapter = new ServiceHistoryListAdapter(YourActivityName.this,serviceHistoryDataList,getLayoutInflater());
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this.

```
ServiceHistoryListAdapter adapter = new ServiceHistoryListAdapter(ActivityName.this,serviceHistoryDataList,getLayoutInflater());
```